# while loop illegal start of type problems

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

Hey i am getting error that stats that it is an illegal start of type at the start of the while loop:

```
public class hello {

    public static void main (String [] arg) {
        int sum1=sum(7, 13);
    }

    public static int sum(int x, int y) { 
        int z=0;
    }

    while (y > 0) {
        z = z + x; 
        y--;
    }

    return (z)
}
}
```

Comment: You cannot put a `while` loop outside of a method body like that.  Get in the habit of indenting your code properly, and these sorts of errors are **much** easier to see.

Comment: You have an extra curly bracket (}) after the line 'int z=0;' And as Reimeus mentioned indent your code properly so these errors can be easily captured.

Comment: To make your life easier use an IDE.  Netbeans/Eclipse/....

Answer (score 1):

Remove the brace after `int z = 0` and add a semi-colon after `return (z)`.

As chenchuk says, `multiply` would be a more correct name for the method, so I've gone ahead and changed that. I've popped a suggestion in there too, in the comment just inside your `while` loop.

Like this:

```
public class Hello {

    public static void main(String[] arg) {
        int sum1 = multiply(7, 13);
    }

    public static int multiply(int x, int y) {
        int z = 0;

        while (y > 0) {
            // You can say z += x; here, think of it as shorthand
            z = z + x;
            y--;
        }

        return z;
    }

}
```

Comment: Beautiful indented code... also you change the 'hello' to 'Hello' . i would suggest to change method name from 'sum' to 'mul' (multiply)